# Showing null rows on a quiz application when user has no quiz results

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Summary of problem: I have a CakePHP/MySQL web application. Users do quizzes to be awarded badges. Each quiz has a level (1 up to 5) to represent difficulty (1 = Easy, 5 = difficult).

I have 3 tables:

- **quizzes** : A series of quizzes, each of which have a difficulty level 1 - 5 (quizzes.test_level) field and a unique ID (quizzes.id).
- **badge_structure** : A list of quizzes which are required to gain a particular badge. Foreign key to 'quizzes' is badge_structure.quiz_id. This table contains multiple quizzes at each test_level.
- **results** : A list of users results for a particular quiz. Foreign key is results.quiz_id. There is also a results.user_id to link to a 'users' table. Results are only stored in this table if the user has passed a quiz: If there is no results.quiz_id in this table for a given user, that user has not passed a particular quiz.

**The problem I'm facing is I cannot work out which level the user has passed.**

My application needs to show a star rating (1 - 5) based on quiz results for a given user. They must have completed **all** quizzes at a particular level (quizzes.test_level) to be awarded the star for a given badge, i.e.

quizzes.test_level = 1 (1 star)
quizzes.test_level = 2 (2 stars)

*For the code below assume badge_structure.id = 3 (Badge number 3) and user.id = 257*

```
SELECT MAX(q.test_level) AS badge_level 
 FROM badges_structure bs 
 JOIN quizzes q ON bs.quiz_id = q.id 
 JOIN results r ON bs.quiz_id = r.quiz_id 
 WHERE bs.badge_id = 3 AND r.user_id = 257 
 ORDER BY q.test_level ASC
```

This will give me the maximum test_level of a quiz a user has done, for a given badge. But I don't know whether they have passed that level, I only know that they have done quizzes that are within that level.

If I run something like this:

```
SELECT bs.badge_id, bs.quiz_id, q.test_level 
FROM badges_structure bs 
LEFT JOIN quizzes q ON bs.quiz_id = q.id 
LEFT JOIN results r ON bs.quiz_id = r.quiz_id 
WHERE bs.badge_id = 3 AND r.user_id = 257 
ORDER BY q.test_level ASC
```

I can see the quizzes and levels they have done, but it doesn't tell me the whole badge_structure for that badge, because it's not including rows where they haven't yet got results.

How is it possible to see the badge structure and have a column which is 'null' if the user has no quiz results for a particular quiz ID?

Comment: So far none of this is in CakePHP language. What do your actual CakePHP queries look like? I'm hoping you're doing find() instead of query()..that is if you're using CakePHP 2.X...also important to know which version of Cake you're using.

Comment: Cake version 2.5.4. I had resorted to using $db->fetchAll type queries because Cake doesn't seem efficient when it comes to the types of queries (and number of rows/results) I want to return *in this particular part of the application*. The rest of the application is using Cake's active record approach. I'm not really bothered whether I use Cake or a  pure SQL query, or a combination - any solution that works would be appreciated here.